# failed to send request in soap XML with docx attachment for c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send http soap request with attchment file
and I can't figure out what's wrong with my code
when I try to execution the line
StreamReader stmreader = new StreamReader(requestStream);
and I get error {"ExceptionMessage":"Stream was not readable."}

I was able to sent the requst with Fiddler

```
   filePath = @"C:\Users\xx\Desktop\test.txt";

        var uri = "http://xx.xx/axis/services/USD_R11_WebService";
        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{0}\";\r\n" +
            "Content-ID: <{0}>;\r\n" +
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii; name={0}\r\n\r\n";
        string boundary = "\"----=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "\"";
        byte[] boundarybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");



        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";

        request.ContentType = "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
        request.Headers.Add("MIME-Version", "1.0");

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDocument xmlFile = new XmlDocument();

            string xmlPayload = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ser=""http://www.ca.com/UnicenterServicePlus/ServiceDesk"">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <ser:createAttachment>
                            <sid>1716344509</sid>
                            <repositoryHandle>doc_rep</repositoryHandle>
                            <objectHandle>cr:635354</objectHandle>
                            <description>TEST</description>
                            <fileName>TEST</fileName>
                         </ser:createAttachment>
                      </soapenv:Body>
                   </soapenv:Envelope>";

            soapEnvelopeDocument.LoadXml(xmlPayload);

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                byte[] formbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                requestStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
                int bytesLeft = 0;

                while ((bytesLeft = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesLeft);
                }

                StreamReader stmreader = new StreamReader(requestStream);
                string webexception = stmreader.ReadToEnd();
                soapEnvelopeDocument.Save(requestStream);
            }
```

Comment: check the CanReed property of the stream,it couldn't be read by desigin

Comment: The CadRead property returns a false value. when I send the same request in fiddler I get success 200. 
Which property can give me the entire request as text?